# Is there a way to place the appbar at the bottom in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dock, appbar

Is there a way to dock the appbar at the bottom in flutter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`AppBar` is just a widget like any other. You can place it wherever you want.

Even in the `bottomNavigationBar` field of `Scaffold`.

```
final appBar = new AppBar(title: new Text("data"));
return new Scaffold(
  body: new Center(
    child: new FlatButton(
      child: new Text("data"),
    ),
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: new SizedBox(
    height: appBar.preferredSize.height,
    child: appBar,
  ),
);
```

Although you may as well use `BottomAppBar` in this situation.

Comment: I tried bottomNavigationBar, but what it did was pull the bottom edge of the appBar all the way to the bottom, son now it fills the entire screen.
This is the example I'm using which I'm trying to place on the bottom, BottomAppBar doesn't have the same properties as AppBar so it won't work.
https://flutter.io/catalog/samples/app-bar-bottom/

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue - put the AppBar in a constrained box set to kToolbarHeight (or whatever size you want):

```
bottomNavigationBar: ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: kToolbarHeight),
  child: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    title: const Text('Title'),
    centerTitle: true,
  ),
)
```